# How to Use Many2one Field as selection?

Tags: python, odoo

on Odoo, I want to create a many2one field which show some items created according to another field(named 'A') and can be changed once field 'A' is changed.

I have tried to use `field.Selection`, but failed and I switch to `field.Many2one`; and until now I don't complete this.

```py
class Selection(models.Model):
    _name = 'selection.model'

    _rec_name = 'select'
    select = fields.Char(string='selections', required=True)

class Checks(models.Model):
    _name = 'buy.goods'

    strs = fields.Char()
    results = fields.Many2one('selection.model', string='Selections')

    @api.onchange('strs')
    def _get_results(self):
        goods = self.strs.split(',')
```

I want to use the list of words of 'goods' as items of 'results' field and once content of 'strs' field is changed, the list of 'goods' is changed and items of 'results' should be changed automaticly.

Comment: Your question is confusing (last section), can you be more specific.

Comment: in xml file add widget selection to this field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you define the form view in XML you need to add a widget called selection. Through this way you can use your many2one field as a selection field.

For example:

```
<field name='results' widget='selection'/>
```

ps: clear cache and try it !